# jQuery ajax return nothing even I set the dataType as text

Tags: jquery, ajax

I used jQuery ajax to get the captcha validation result from http://www.opencaptcha.com/validate.php as **1**,

I found that I can't get the result from the ajax call even I set the return dataType as `text` as **2**

However, if I enter the query link in browser, I get the message pass/fail as **3**.

I would like to ask is there any mistake on my code so that I can't get the result on `Firebug console` with the `console.log(data)`?

Thanks

**1 Code**

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.opencaptcha.com/validate.php',
    data: {
        img: timestamp, 
        ans: $('input[name=captcha_answer]').val()
    },
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data)
    },
    dataType: 'text'
});
```

**2 Firebug console(no return/return empty)**
[image: Firebug console]

**3 Browser sources**
[image: Browser sources]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are sending cross-domain ajax. Use datatype `jsonp` (json with padding):

```
$.ajax({
url: 'http://www.opencaptcha.com/validate.php',
data: {
    img: timestamp, 
    ans: $('input[name=captcha_answer]').val()
},
success: function(data) {
    console.log(data)
},
dataType: 'jsonp'
});
```

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3506306/1313143).

### Important:

It appears though, that [Opencaptcha](http://www.opencaptcha.com/) does not support ajax with jsonp. You will have to do this check server-side. What you **can do** is send an ajax request to your **own server** (jsonp not required this time), where you handle the rest.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I can't set `$_GET['callback']` on http://www.opencaptcha.com, so any alternative? Thanks.